# How do I remove the Flex 4 context menu?

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, flash-builder

On my web app, I want to be able to remove the Flash context menu and only leave the ones really needed like the textarea contextmenu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to remove those in Flash Player in the browser.  Please go vote for this bug:
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14327